# Retrieve data on list view and go to specific class base from the data that click

Tags: android, mysql

I have table in mysql database (tbl_category) which have field names "Id","Category". The data is retrieve/fetch successfully already. i found that tutorial from here https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-mysql-tutorial-to-perform-basic-crud-operation/ . In that tutorial their is a Intent function, which means that when the listview is retrieve the data from tbl_catagory, user can click the data and go to (sample.class). But consider that i fetch three(3) data (Picture,Music,Video). What i want to do is when i click Picture it go to Picture.class, the same as Music goes to Music.class and Videos.class.

here how it show the data

```
private void showEmployee(){
  JSONObject jsonObject = null;
  ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
  try {
    jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
    JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_JSON_ARRAY);
    for(int i = 0; i<result.length(); i++){
       JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
       //String id = jo.getString(Config.TAG_ID);
       String name = jo.getString(Config.TAG_CAT);

       HashMap<String,String> employees = new HashMap<>();
       //  employees.put(Config.TAG_ID,id);
       employees.put(Config.TAG_CAT,name);
       list.add(employees);
    }
  } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
    lec.this, list, R.layout.list_item,
    new String[]{Config.TAG_ID,Config.TAG_CAT},
    new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.name});
  listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

from here where intent occur

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, fetching_calculus.class);
  HashMap<String,String> map =(HashMap)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
  String empId = map.get(Config.TAG_CAT).toString();
  intent.putExtra(Config.EMP_ID,empId);
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

your help will enhance my knowledge as a beginner  android developer.

Comment: U have to make the check that where is the user going to click on the view....Simply their is the setOnclickListener() method to perform any click on the view...And for the listview/recyclview u have to use the setOnItemClickListener() method to perform the click

Comment: sorry i re-edit my question i forgot to include the code where intent occur.

Comment: `switch(item.getItemType()) { case "VIDEO" : useVideoClass(); break; case "MUSIC" : useMusicClass(); break ... }`

Comment: @selvin thank you. but i dont understand where to put that code.. and the VIDEO MUSIC PICTURES are not declared as a string. it was fetch to mysql database.